# Fault code: P0812: Reverse Input Circuit.

Tags: honda, civic

I've a 2007 Honda Civic. It has 155k in odometer. It has been in an accident recently. The reverse gear indicator light on the dash board is turned off. The fault code say P0812: Reverse Input Circuit. I took it to couple of auto mechanics but they are not familiar with this problem or how to fix it. I could use some expert advice here.

Comment: Is it possible that the sensor in the shift console has a cut wire due to the accident.  The 'gear' sensor in failed state could give this code.  OR...a cut wire to the sensor.

Comment: It might be possible.

Comment: check the ecm. apparently the jolt from an accident can make the battery bump against the ecm. the back side of the ecm cover has a raised section that can hit the circuit board and cause an open circuit

Comment: @ZihanIbrahim   you should also have a check engine light on.  The ECM piece mentioned above is possible as is a faulty switch on in your shifter when you put it into reverse.   Did you ever get this issue resolved?